# Is there a way to add tokenised text from a csv file to that same file but in a new column in Python?

Tags: python, csv, token

I'm using Python on a JupiterLab notebook, and have been trying to add some tokenised text, of comments scraped from reddit, to a new column of a csv file (ideally the same file from which the text comes from, otherwise a new file that keeps the same column as the original one plus the tokenised text one).

This is my code so far:

```py
with open("/filepath/example.csv", 'r') as csvinput:
    with open("/filepath/example2.csv", 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput)
        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('Tokens')
        all.append(row)

        for row in reader:
            comment = row["body"]
            tokens = word_tokenize(comment)
            print(tokens)
```

and this is the error that pops up:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Now I understand that it isn't possible to use append with dictread, so is there any other way to do this? Any suggestion on tokenisation would be really appreciated too, as I'm very new to Python.
Thank you for any response!

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory, you are trying to append to a dict, that is not possible. Rather create a a new key in the dict, with an empty list, then append to it.  `row['Tokens'] = []` and then later on `row['Tokens'].append(word_tokenize(comment))`

Comment: @alec_djinn Thank you! Follow-up question, how do I add the empty list to the dictionary keys?

Comment: I have already made an example `row['Tokens'] = []` Please be sure you understand the basics of list and dict before coding any further.